# String structure changed

Tags: java

in the following program string is given but out put is like :

```
2015 9?500002666_2782-02_4934177-MR.pdf
```

what is the reason and how to resolve this problem

```
String str = "2015\09\201500002666_2782\002-02_4934177-MR.pdf";
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 5):

A backslash followed by numbers represents an unicode character.

So, in your example `\09`, `\201`, `\002` will be interpreted as unicode character and translated into the corresponding characters.

You need to escape the backslash to preserve the text.

```
String str = "2015\\09\\201500002666_2782\\002-02_4934177-MR.pdf";
System.out.println(str);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/kAiHoK)

Comment: above string is file path and we are saving in database, so i am getting above string from database in this situation how to handle

Comment: @Moulali If you get the string from DB, the string comes is already escaped, so if it comes wrong it means that it was saved wrong. How is the string saved to the DB?

Comment: like 2015\09\201500002666_2782\002-02_4934177-MR.pdf

Comment: @Moulali That can't be possible. Either the string is not saved like this or you are doing something on the string after fetching it from the DB. Can you update the question with the full code which saves the string to the DB and that reads the string from DB?